# Vaadin Grid cell not showing multiline rows

Tags: java, grid, vaadin

With Vaadin Grid, I want to generate multiline cells for every cell that have more content in cell that overlaps its width.

I have allready tried:

- java `\n` new line character and CSS stylings like `white-space: pre;` but it does not seem to work. (This solution worked for Table)
- custom renderer `setRenderer(HtmlRenderer)` with `</br>`tags and different CSS display settings

Desired result:
[image: Wanted result, implemented with Vaadin Table]

Comment: UPDATE: Vaadins Grid 2 comes with 'Variable row height support' https://vaadin.com/blog/-/blogs/-vaadin-grid-2-0-with-million-dollar-scrolling
There is no Java API supporting it yet, but there might be alternative:
"With Vaadin Framework 8.0, we included an enabling piece of technology called HTML imports. This allows WebComponents such as <vaadin-grid> to be used together with Framework 8.0."

Answer (score 3):

Vaadin Grid still doesn't have native support for multiline columns but you can try some improvisation, on example I suggest to see the Vaadin forum discussion on the link:
[Grid - How to display multiple lines in one cell](https://vaadin.com/forum/#!/thread/10036547/10036546)

Also you can try to create custom renderer for the Grid.

Comment: Thank you for your anwser Dragan. Could you provide some sample implementation?

Comment: See the link https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/components/components-grid.html#components.grid.renderer I suggest to try implement HtmlRenderer

Comment: I have done that but, row is not vertically streched, so no content is shown after first <br>.

Comment: For the first it seems like a Vaadin bug. I think that you can note as bug on https://vaadin.com/bug . Secondly, you can use: https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/componentrenderer add on and place a VerticalLayout with labels in column of you grid. It is easier than creating your own renderer. But creating your own renderer is more performant I think.

Comment: Thank you Dragan for provided workaround. But i'm looking for native implementation.

Answer (score 3):

For people with **large text** in columns and who want to display large data in Grid Columns without having them cutoff by default:

1. Add a Style name to your grid:

   `grid.addStyleName("commentsGrid");`
2. Add some style names to your rows and cells if you would like to customize them:

   ```
   grid.setRowStyleGenerator(rowRef -> {// Java 8
       return "bigRows";
   });
   ```

   and

   ```
   grid.setCellStyleGenerator(new Grid.CellStyleGenerator(){
        @Override
        public String getStyle(CellReference cellReference) {
            return "bigCell";
        }
   });
   ```
3. For me the problem column was comments. So surround the text with `p` tag with style class *wrap* and a fixed width.

   ```
   Converter<String, String> commentsConverter = new Converter<String,  String>(){
           @Override
           public String convertToModel(String value, Class<? extends String> targetType, Locale locale)
                   throws com.vaadin.data.util.converter.Converter.ConversionException {

               return value;
           }

           @Override
           public String convertToPresentation(String value, Class<? extends String> targetType, Locale locale)
                   throws com.vaadin.data.util.converter.Converter.ConversionException {
               if(value !=null){
                   return "<p class=\"wrap\">"+value+"</p>";
               }else{
                   return "";
               }
           }

           @Override
           public Class<String> getModelType() {
               return String.class;
           }

           @Override
           public Class<String> getPresentationType() {
               return String.class;
           }

       };
       grid.getColumn("comments").setRenderer(new HtmlRenderer(), commentsConverter);
       grid.getColumn("comments").setWidth(700d);
   ```
4. Then i styled the classes mentioned above as follows:

   ```
   .commentsGrid td{
       height:150px !important;
    }

   p.wrap{
     width: 45em;
     word-wrap: break-word;
     word-break: break-all;
     white-space: normal; 
   }
   ```

And i got result like this:

I am not a CSS ninja, so you can make it way more beautiful than this.

[image]

> If you don't like all rows to have equally large heights then you can  calculate rowHeights on the fly and then set them in step 2. I am not 100% sure.

Answer (score 3):

Another way of fitting long scrolling text into a grid column is to set a row height for the grid and use a component renderer and render a textarea in the grid which contains the text. This works good because if the text is too long the user will get a scrollbar inside the cell to see the overflowed text.

```
Column screen = grid.addComponentColumn(role->{
        TextArea ta = new TextArea();
        ta.setValue(VALUE_PROVIDER_TEXT);
        ta.setStyleName("clear");
        ta.setHeight("100px");
        ta.setReadOnly(true);
        ta.setWidth("150px");
        return ta;
    });
    screen.setWidth(150);
    screen.setCaption("Screens");
    grid.setBodyRowHeight(100);
```

and this in the css

```
  .v-textarea-clear{background-color: transparent;border: none;}
```

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqvu5.png)

Answer (score 1):

With Vaadin 24 we can use a theme variant for this:

```
grid.addThemeVariants(GridVariant.LUMO_WRAP_CELL_CONTENT);
```

Other grid variants are described in the [official docs](https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/components/grid/#theme-variants).

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what i was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add a style renderer to your ceolumns to add a custom css class, where you can place your defined height?

Example:

Java:

```
grid.setCellStyleGenerator(cellRef -> // Java 8
    "heigher");
```

CSS:

```
.v-grid-cell.heigher {
    height: 10em;
}
```

Example coming from: https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/components/components-grid.html

Comment: Thanks for your anwser. Please see updated question.