# Vaadin Grid cell with multiple lines

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I'm using Vaadin 7.6.5.

I am using a Grid component, I have some long strings and I want them to display in multiple lines of the same cell. Is there any solution to solve the issue.Thanks in advance
[image]

And I uses the following code.
`
 Grid myActivitiesGrid=new Grid();

```
myActivitiesGrid.setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.SINGLE);
myActivitiesGrid.addColumn(_CLOSE).setRenderer(new ButtonRenderer(new CloseClickLnr())).setEditable(false);
myActivitiesGrid.addColumn(_START).setRenderer(new ButtonRenderer(new StartClickLnr())).setEditable(false);
myActivitiesGrid.addColumn(_PKEY, Integer.class).setHidden(true).setEditable(false);
myActivitiesGrid.addColumn(_ACTIVITY).setEditable(false);
myActivitiesGrid.addColumn(_ACTIVITY_TYPE).setEditable(false);

 private void populateGrid()
{
        if (!activity.getActivityStatus().equals(ActivityStatus.NEW) && !activity.isRoutine())
        {
        myActivitiesGrid.addRow(_CLOSE, _START, activity.getPkey(), activity.getActivityName(), activity.getActivityType()); 
        }
}`
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vaadin Grid cell not showing multiline rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36157180/vaadin-grid-cell-not-showing-multiline-rows)